# std::condition_variable wait_until surprising behaviour

Tags: c++11, visual-c++-2013

Building with VS2013, specifying `time_point::max()` to a condition variable's `wait_until` results in an immediate timeout.

This seems unintuitive - I would naively expect `time_point::max()` to wait indefinitely (or at least a *very* long time). Can anyone confirm if this is documented, expected behaviour or something specific to MSVC?

Sample program below; note replacing `time_point::max()` with `now + std::chrono::hours(1)` gives the expected behaviour (`wait_for` exits once cv is notified, with no timeout)

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <functional>

void fire_cv( std::mutex *mx, std::condition_variable *cv )
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*mx);
    printf("firing cv\n");
    cv->notify_one();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::condition_variable test_cv;
    std::mutex test_mutex;

    std::future<void> s;
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(test_mutex);
        s = std::async(std::launch::async, std::bind(fire_cv, &test_mutex, &test_cv));
        printf("blocking on cv\n");
        std::cv_status result = test_cv.wait_until( lock, std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::max() );

        //std::cv_status result = test_cv.wait_until( lock, now + std::chrono::hours(1) ); // <--- this works as expected!
        printf("%s\n", (result==std::cv_status::timeout) ? "timeout" : "no timeout");
    }
    s.wait();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I see the same behavior with your example on gcc 5.4.0, so it doesn't appear to be just a bug in MSVC's standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged MSCV 2015's implementation, and `wait_until` calls `wait_for` internally, which is implemented like this:

```
template<class _Rep,
        class _Period>
        _Cv_status wait_for(
            unique_lock<mutex>& _Lck,
            const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& _Rel_time)
        {   // wait for duration
        _STDEXT threads::xtime _Tgt = _To_xtime(_Rel_time); // Bug!
        return (wait_until(_Lck, &_Tgt));
        }
```

The bug here is that `_To_xtime` overflows, which results in **undefined behavior**, and the result is a *negative* `time_point`:

```
template<class _Rep,
    class _Period> inline
    xtime _To_xtime(const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& _Rel_time)
    {   // convert duration to xtime
    xtime _Xt;
    if (_Rel_time <= chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>::zero())
        {   // negative or zero relative time, return zero
        _Xt.sec = 0;
        _Xt.nsec = 0;
        }
    else
        {   // positive relative time, convert
        chrono::nanoseconds _T0 =
            chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
        _T0 += chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(_Rel_time); //Overflow!
        _Xt.sec = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(_T0).count();
        _T0 -= chrono::seconds(_Xt.sec);
        _Xt.nsec = (long)_T0.count();
        }
    return (_Xt);
    }
```

`std::chrono::nanoseconds` by default stores its value in a `long long`, and so after its definition, `_T0` has a value of `1'471'618'263'082'939'000` (this changes obviously). Adding `_Rel_time` (`9'223'244'955'544'505'510`) results definitely in signed overflow.

We have already passed every negative `time_point` possible, so a timeout happens.

Comment: So there's a range of large values that you can pass to `wait_for` that will just not work. And apparently GCC has a similar issue. Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: @moonshadow Jup, but I don't think that is intended. I will probably fill in a bug report to MSVC and gcc